# Capture credit card detail using Observer Magento 2

Tags: payment, checkout, magento2, payment-method

I have set authorized.net payment method for custom purpose. I have set one observer which is sales_order_place_before. Still observer is working but when i fill credit card detail in checkout page than click on place order than i am not able to get credit card detail on magento 2.0.2. Only i got the method and method title or CC_type, cc_number etc. are blank value.
If you are know about this issue than please help me as soon as possible.